# Customizing the way the form is displayed to admin user

Tags: forms, theming

I am developing a module which requires an administrator form.The admin will enter some settings data which will be saved in database.Then i will use these settings to display information to the website users depending on the settings chosen by admin.

So for administrator screen i need the form to be displayed like this

HEADING_ONE    HEADING_TWO     HEADING_THREE     HEADING_FOUR
TEXTFIELD_ONE  TEXTFIELD_TWO   TEXTFIELD_THREE     TEXTFIELD_FOUR

I need to have a table like structure. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`system_settings_form`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_settings_form/7) to make admin form and [`theme_table`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) to make a table output.